# How to go about creating a Python package with only one module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module written that I'd like to make a "package" some day. Right now I keep it in a subfolder with the same name inside a directory on my Python path (with an empty `__init__.py` module in there with it). The problem is, to import these modules into other programs (and get Spyder's autocompletion to recognize the module's contents) I have to do something like

```
from modulename import modulename
```

or

```
import modulename.modulename as modulename
```

when I'd rather just

```
import modulename
```

I have tried making the `__init__.py` inside the directory import everything from the module, but this doesn't work with Spyder's autocompletion. What's the appropriate way to do this? Numpy has many modules but still has some available at the top level namespace. It seems it does this by e.g.

```
import core
from core import *
```

Is this the route I should take, or is my problem the fact that the module name is the same as the folder name?

Comment: I've always used the approach you mention, ie putting `import` statements in `__init__.py`, curious to hear what the best practice for this is though as the python documentation is not super clear on this point

Comment: Add `modulename` itself to your search path. I mean the package folder.

Comment: Do not forget to mark some answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Takahiro recommended, it's not a great idea to have a module with the same name as a package, but it's not an impossibility.

The `__init__.py` in the **modulename** directory can be the following:

```py
from .modulename import *
```

Then, for example, **modulename.py** in that directory might be:

```py
def foo():
    print('I am foo')
```

Then a client program could be

```py
import modulename

modulename.foo()
```

or

```py
from modulename import foo

foo()
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a module with a same name within its package.
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Answer (score 0):

In the question title you ask about package with only one module but later you ask about Spyder. Anyways, I still believe this can be seen as a duplicate of [this question from StackExchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/243044). There is an excellent [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/243045/386836) by the user [Martijn Pieters](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/55400/martijn-pieters). In order to provide some answer, not just a link I will sum it up bellow.

You do not have to create a package (subfolder) for your module (file). Just put your `module.py` file into the root of your project where e.g. `setup.py is`. From Martijn Pieters' answer:

> You do the simplest thing that works for you. ...
>
> Packages are useful for creating an additional namespace and/or for organising your code across multiple modules.
>
> If you want examples: [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) is a distribution of just [one module](https://github.com/benjaminp/six)

There is a mention of such single module distributions on [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-individual-modules) of the Python documentation.